# How Do I Call ETH USD Price Using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I intend to print the USD value of ETH from

"https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/"

using JavaScript. However, when I include the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
parseJson(json);
}
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

  function parseJson(json) {
  var time = "<b>Last Updated : " + json["time"]["updated"] + "</b>";
  var usdValue = "$" + json["eth"]["price.usd"]["rate"];

  document.getElementById("data").innerHTML =
    usdValue
 }
 </script>
```

in my HTML file, along with other scripts of other Price APIs, the code above returns nothing. What am I doing wrong? I need help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Something like this

```html
<body>
 <div id="data" />
 <script type="text/javascript">
  
    var json = new XMLHttpRequest(); // start a new variable to store the JSON in
json.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { // if HTTP header 200 - ok
    var object = JSON.parse(this.responseText); // set the variable 'object' to whatever we get back, in our case it is an array of 10 different arrays

  for(var i=0;i<object.length;i++){   // looping through json

  var item = object[i];
       if(item["symbol"] === "ETH"){   // finding when symbol is ETH
              var usdValue = "$" + item["price_usd"];    // Fetching price_usd value
              document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = usdValue;

       }
   }
  }
};


json.open(
  "GET", // method
  "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/", // url
  true // async
); // initialise the request
json.send(); //send request

  
 </script>
</body>
```

Run the code snippet

Comment: Hello Amit, thanks for replying. Yes. I am quite certain that is how it should look like, but it still doesn't print the USD value. Another way would be; https://jsfiddle.net/iamselasie/gc8s32ko/14/ but this code is poorly written and breaks my HTML page

Comment: there is typo mistake now try the code . Is it Working ?

Comment: No, please. I checked in JS Fiddle.

Comment: @SydeEphekt    Run the code snippet  or check this https://jsfiddle.net/jaL5k8eu/    I have Updated answer according to your requirement

Comment: Yes, that works on the snippet, however, it doesn't show up on my index.html page. Could it be that I have another script in my HTML, (making multiple requests) that's preventing the current from running?

Comment: why don't you debug it in the console may be some exceptions are occurring?

Comment: alright, supposing I wanted to call the script from a js file instead of writing it directly in the HTML file, what would be a clever way to execute this? NB: I already have a JS file  linked to my HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

1. According https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/, the return value of JSON.parse(this.responseText) will be a json array. So pass json[0] to your parseJson().
2. The parsed json doesn't have field/property of 'time' or 'eth'. I suggest you use following code to get what you want.

```js
    
let time = `<b>Last Updated : ${new Date(parseInt(json['last_updated'])).toDateString()}</b>`;
let usdValue = `\$${json['price_usd']}`;
```

Comment: Hello Cheng, thanks for your answer! Supposing I wanted to call this JSON script outside of html, what would be a way to execute it?

Comment: You use document.write() in your fiddle, that's why it breaks your HTML page. But Amit use <div id="data" /> in his html body, then set the div's content with document.getElementById("data").innerHTML. Do you note the difference? It's totally nothing about separate js file. As Amit said, use browser's dev tool to help you figuring out what's your really question.